# How do I use Filestack's security feature?

Tags: javascript, file-upload, image-uploading, image-upload

I'm completely lost here. I want to use Filestack's security features and I'm unable to get it to work. I have read the documentation and I'm doing everything they say, but it still won't work. Here is the code I have:

```
const filestack_apikey = MY_API_KEY;
const filestack_policy = MY_POLICY;
const filestack_signature = MY_SIGNATURE;
const filestack_security = {
    policy: filestack_policy,
    signature: filestack_signature
};
const fsClient = filestack.init(filestack_apikey, filestack_security);

function openFilePicker () {
    fsClient.pick({
        fromSources: ["local_file_system"],
        maxSize: 100*1024*1024,
        maxFiles: 1,
        storeTo: {
            location: 's3',
            path: MY_PATH,
            container: MY_CONTAINER,
            region: 'us-east-1'
        }
    }).then(function (response) {
        console.log('response = ' + JSON.stringify(response));
    }
});
```

The file picker opens up just fine. I select a file from my computer and then I see the file in the file picker. But when I click the "Upload" button I see this response:

```
response = {"filesUploaded":[],"filesFailed":[{...}]}
```

What am I doing wrong? By the way, I do have the "Use Security" button checked on my Filestack developer portal.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure your keys currently have security enabled in the developer portal? Security must be enabled for it to work.